# Access hook_preprocess_node variables from page controller

Tags: 8, page-controller

I have a custom controller created for a custom URL, where the URL is a URL for an existing node with an additional parameter. The display for the URL defined by the controller needs to use the the same template for the base node route, and the controller just uses a service to get additional data and merge it with the base node data.

To be more specific, I have a node type called `product_group`. It has an entity reference field called `field_products` that attaches `commerce_product` entities. The URL alias pattern for `product_group` nodes is `/products/[node-title]`. My controller is for the URL `/products/[node-title]/[sku]`, where `sku` is the commerce_product sku. The controller gets the data from the URL, loads the base `product_group` node object, uses the `sku` value to get the `commerce_product` object, and then I have a custom service that gets a bunch of additional data from the product and associated variation.

The tricky part is that the display at the `/products/[node-title]/[sku]` URL is the same as the display at the `/products/[node-title]` URL, with some additional data from the product itself added in. Therefore, I need to get all of the `$variables` data that is available in `hook_preprocess_node()` function in my controller and add my new data on top of it. The problem is, I can't figure how to access it. From what I've seen, you can't access data in a preprocess hook directly from a controller, but I'm guessing there has to be some way I can render the `product_group` node and get the variables that are available in `hook_preprocess_node`. Am I correct, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: What exactly you want to access there? Can't you simply retrieve it from the node object in the controller?

Comment: No, all I really want is what is available as the `$variables` parameter that is available in the preprocess function - I don't want to have to re-create the wheel and generate it all myself again.

Comment: Are there specific variables you want? my first thought is that preprocess is theme layer, and controller is below that, so they probably don't share any information.

Comment: Yeah, basically just the `$variables['content']`element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be an incorrect `#theme` template name in my returned render array. The node type I was adding content to was called `product_group`, but in my controller, I returned this:

```
 return [
   '#theme' => 'node__product_resource__full',
   '#product_group' => $content,
   '#node' => $pg_node,
   '#view_mode' => 'full',
 ];
```

`product_resource` is a valid content type in the site. Once I changed it to

```
'#theme' => 'node__product_group__full',
```

It worked fine.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer.

Comment: I will when it allows me to. I have to wait 2 days, and as of now, I can't do it until tomorrow.